# How can i use Hybridauth for facebook tabs?

Tags: facebook

I'm searching the way i can integrate hybridauth into a facebook tab app. I only must know an user id who is connecting to the tab ,  Any idea?

Comment: hybridauth is multiple social providers, if you need only FB you can use regular FB API

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to integrate multiple social providers in your app.

You can use popular socialauth library. The library also help you to integrate faceebook, twitter and myspace.

Here is link.

http://code.google.com/p/socialauth-android/